# Scikit-learn - feature reduction using RFECV and GridSearch. Where are the coefficients stored?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Scikit-learn RFECV to select most significant features for a logistic regression using a Cross Validation.  Assume X is a [n,x] dataframe of features, and y represents the response variable:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
import sklearn
import sklearn.linear_model as lm
import sklearn.grid_search as gs

#  Create a logistic regression estimator 
logreg = lm.LogisticRegression()

# Use RFECV to pick best features, using Stratified Kfold
rfecv =   RFECV(estimator=logreg, cv=StratifiedKFold(y, 3), scoring='roc_auc')

# Fit the features to the response variable
rfecv.fit(X, y)

# Put the best features into new df X_new
X_new = rfecv.transform(X)

# 
pipe = make_pipeline(preprocessing.StandardScaler(), lm.LogisticRegression())

# Define a range of hyper parameters for grid search
C_range = 10.**np.arange(-5, 1)
penalty_options = ['l1', 'l2']

skf = StratifiedKFold(y, 3)
param_grid = dict(logisticregression__C=C_range,  logisticregression__penalty=penalty_options)

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=skf, scoring='roc_auc')

grid.fit(X_new, y)
```

Two questions:

a) Is this the correct process for feature, hyper-parameter selection and fitting?

b) Where can I find the fitted coefficients for the selected features?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Is this the correct process for feature selection?**
This is ONE of the many ways of feature selection. Recursive feature elimination is an automated approach to this, [others are listed in scikit.learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html). They have different pros and cons, and usually feature selection is best achieved by also involving common sense and trying models with different features. RFE is a quick way of selecting a good set of features, but does not necessarily give you the ultimately best. By the way, you don't need to build your StratifiedKFold separately. If you just set the `cv` parameter to `cv=3`, both `RFECV` and `GridSearchCV` will automatically use StratifiedKFold if the y values are binary or multiclass, which I'm assuming is most likely the case since you are using `LogisticRegression`.
You can also combine

```
# Fit the features to the response variable
rfecv.fit(X, y)

# Put the best features into new df X_new
X_new = rfecv.transform(X)
```

into

```
X_new = rfecv.fit_transform(X, y)
```

**Is this the correct process for hyper-parameter selection?**
GridSearchCV is basically an automated way of systematically trying a whole set of combinations of model parameters and picking the best among these according to some performance metric. It's a good way of finding well-suited parameters, yes.

**Is this the correct process for fitting?**
Yes, this is a valid way of fitting the model. When you call `grid.fit(X_new, y)`, it makes a grid of `LogisticRegression` estimators (each with a set of parameters that are tried) and fits each of them. It will keep the one with the best performance under `grid.best_estimator_`, the parameters of this estimator in `grid.best_params_` and the performance score for this estimator under `grid.best_score_`. It will return itself, and not the best estimator. Remember that with incoming new X values that you will use the model to predict on, you have to apply the transform with the fitted RFECV model. So, you can actually add this step to the pipeline as well.

**Where can I find the fitted coefficients for the selected features?**
The `grid.best_estimator_` attribute is a `LogisticRegression` object with all this information, so `grid.best_estimator_.coef_` has all the coefficients (and `grid.best_estimator_.intercept_` is the intercept). Note that to be able to get this `grid.best_estimator_`, the `refit` parameter on `GridSearchCV` needs to be set to `True`, but this is the default anyway.

Comment: thanks alot for this.   Very helpful.   One thing I do not understand is the need for transform:  If it selects n features, what exactly gets 'transformed'?  (and, btw, I am not sure how it determines this - there must be a threshold).  My heuristic I am using is RFECV selects the 'n' best features and drops the others....

Comment: Further to my question above, I am getting error message:  'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'coef_' when I attempt to view coef_ as described by you above.   Also curious to know why you claim Stratified K Fold is chosen for any classification problem (which it is):   I thought Kfold was the default, with stratified Kfold being used for unbalanced classes (which I have).

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, you need to do a train-validation-test split for your sample data. Where train set is used to tuned your normal params, validation set for tuning hyperparameters in grid search, and test set for performance evaluation. Here is one way to do this.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import pandas as pd


# simulate some artifical data so that I can show you the result of each intermediate step
# 1000 obs, X dim 1000-by-100, 2 different y labels with unbalanced weights
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=100, n_informative=5, n_classes=2, weights=[0.1, 0.9])

X.shape

Out[78]: (1000, 100)

y.shape

Out[79]: (1000,)

# Nested Cross-Validation, this returns an train/test index interator
split = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
# to take a look at the split, you will see it has 5 tuples
list(split)
# the 1st fold
train_index = list(split)[0][0]

Out[80]: array([  0,   1,   2, ..., 997, 998, 999])

test_index = list(split)[0][1]

Out[81]: array([  5,  12,  17, ..., 979, 982, 984])

# let's play with just one iteration for now
# your pipe
pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression())

# set up params
params_space = dict(logisticregression__C=10.0**np.arange(-5,1),
                    logisticregression__penalty=['l1', 'l2'],
                    logisticregression__class_weight=[None, 'auto'])

# apply your grid search only in train data but with a futher cv step
# so original train set has [gscv_train, gscv_validation] where the latter is used to tune hyperparameters
# all performance is still evaluated in a separated held-out 'test' set
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, params_space, cv=StratifiedKFold(y[train_index], n_folds=3), scoring='roc_auc')
# fit the data on train set
grid.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index])

# to get the params of your estimator, call your gscv
grid.best_estimator_
Out[82]: 
Pipeline(steps=[('standardscaler', StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)), ('logisticregression', LogisticRegression(C=0.10000000000000001, class_weight=None, dual=False,
          fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100,
          multi_class='ovr', penalty='l1', random_state=None,
          solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001, verbose=0))])


# the performance in validation set
grid.grid_scores_
Out[83]: 
[mean: 0.50000, std: 0.00000, params: {'logisticregression__C': 1.0000000000000001e-05, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l1'},
 mean: 0.87975, std: 0.01753, params: {'logisticregression__C': 1.0000000000000001e-05, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2'},
 mean: 0.50000, std: 0.00000, params: {'logisticregression__C': 1.0000000000000001e-05, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'auto', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l1'},
 mean: 0.87985, std: 0.01746, params: {'logisticregression__C': 1.0000000000000001e-05, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'auto', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2'},
 mean: 0.50000, std: 0.00000, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.0001, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l1'},
 mean: 0.88033, std: 0.01707, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.0001, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2'},
 mean: 0.50000, std: 0.00000, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.0001, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'auto', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l1'},
 mean: 0.87975, std: 0.01732, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.0001, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'auto', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2'},
 mean: 0.50000, std: 0.00000, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.001, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l1'},
 mean: 0.88245, std: 0.01732, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.001, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2'},
 mean: 0.50000, std: 0.00000, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.001, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'auto', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l1'},
 mean: 0.87955, std: 0.01686, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.001, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'auto', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2'},
 mean: 0.50000, std: 0.00000, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.01, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l1'},
 mean: 0.88746, std: 0.02318, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.01, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2'},
 mean: 0.50000, std: 0.00000, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.01, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'auto', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l1'},
 mean: 0.87990, std: 0.01634, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.01, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'auto', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2'},
 mean: 0.94002, std: 0.02959, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.10000000000000001, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l1'},
 mean: 0.87419, std: 0.02174, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.10000000000000001, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2'},
 mean: 0.93508, std: 0.03101, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.10000000000000001, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'auto', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l1'},
 mean: 0.87091, std: 0.01860, params: {'logisticregression__C': 0.10000000000000001, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'auto', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2'},
 mean: 0.88013, std: 0.03246, params: {'logisticregression__C': 1.0, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l1'},
 mean: 0.85247, std: 0.02712, params: {'logisticregression__C': 1.0, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2'},
 mean: 0.88904, std: 0.02906, params: {'logisticregression__C': 1.0, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'auto', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l1'},
 mean: 0.85197, std: 0.02097, params: {'logisticregression__C': 1.0, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'auto', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2'}]


# or the best score among them
grid.best_score_
Out[84]: 0.94002188482393367

# now after finishing training the estimator, we now predict in test set
y_pred = grid.predict(X[test_index])
# since LogisticRegression is probability based model, we have the luxury to get the propability for each obs
y_pred_probs = grid.predict_proba(X[test_index])

Out[87]: 
array([[ 0.0632,  0.9368],
       [ 0.0236,  0.9764],
       [ 0.0227,  0.9773],
       ..., 
       [ 0.0108,  0.9892],
       [ 0.2903,  0.7097],
       [ 0.0113,  0.9887]])

# to get evaluation result, 
print(classification_report(y[test_index], y_pred))

             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.93      0.59      0.72        22
          1       0.95      0.99      0.97       179

avg / total       0.95      0.95      0.95       201



# to put all things together with the nested cross-validation
# generate a pandas dataframe to store prediction probability
kfold_df = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=np.arange(len(y)), columns=unique(y))
report = []  # to store classificaiton report

split = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1)

for train_index, test_index in split:

    grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, params_space, cv=StratifiedKFold(y[train_index], n_folds=3), scoring='roc_auc')

    grid.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index])

    y_pred_probs = grid.predict_proba(X[test_index])
    kfold_df.iloc[test_index, :] = y_pred_probs

    y_pred = grid.predict(X[test_index])
    report.append(classification_report(y[test_index], y_pred))

# your result
print(kfold_df)

Out[88]: 
          0       1
0    0.1710  0.8290
1    0.0083  0.9917
2    0.2049  0.7951
3    0.0038  0.9962
4    0.0536  0.9464
5    0.0632  0.9368
6    0.1243  0.8757
7    0.1150  0.8850
8    0.0796  0.9204
9    0.4096  0.5904
..      ...     ...
990  0.0505  0.9495
991  0.2128  0.7872
992  0.0270  0.9730
993  0.0434  0.9566
994  0.8078  0.1922
995  0.1452  0.8548
996  0.1372  0.8628
997  0.0127  0.9873
998  0.0935  0.9065
999  0.0065  0.9935

[1000 rows x 2 columns]


for r in report:
    print(r)

for r in report:
    print(r)
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.93      0.59      0.72        22
          1       0.95      0.99      0.97       179

avg / total       0.95      0.95      0.95       201

             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.86      0.55      0.67        22
          1       0.95      0.99      0.97       179

avg / total       0.94      0.94      0.93       201

             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.89      0.38      0.53        21
          1       0.93      0.99      0.96       179

avg / total       0.93      0.93      0.92       200

             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.88      0.33      0.48        21
          1       0.93      0.99      0.96       178

avg / total       0.92      0.92      0.91       199

             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.88      0.33      0.48        21
          1       0.93      0.99      0.96       178

avg / total       0.92      0.92      0.91       199
```

Comment: This is very useful and thanks for the code!   I am not sure I understand why I need to hold out some data when using CV:  I thought the entire purpose of CV was to avoid holding out data as in train_test_split.

Comment: interesting observation, your code worked fine for the case where the df was generated, but I needed to use '.iloc' to correctly index my df.

Comment: @GlennBlasius Thanks for pointing out this potential inconsistent behaviour. I see your point: If you are working with a pandas.DataFrame, then the default int index attached to the df might lead to an unexpected selection on split. To avoid this, as you said, you can pass you df but change `.loc` to `iloc`.

Comment: @GlennBlasius The purpose of CV is to select the best algorithm. It's still a kind of optimization (although not in the standard convex optimization, we use a exhaustive grid-search).

Comment: The general rule is that if you are optimizing your algorithm, then a held-out dataset must be available to evaluate the performance (NOT do model selection, but just evaluation, so for test dataset, you shall only apply just one algorithm instead of many of them). The reason for nested CV here is that the standard model do an optimization on internal parameters, the validation set is used for select best hyper parameter, and then a final test set is used for evaluation.

Comment: For some related discussion, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/training-with-the-full-dataset-after-cross-validation

Comment: thanks for the clarification and the additional resources.   One further question regarding your code above:  it seems like you are evaluating model fits for the hyper parameter set for each fold separately:  e.g., each fold in your loop might have a different hyper parameter set selected (via grid.fit inside the loop) making the classification reports on the entire probability set inaccurate.     Am I interpreting this correctly?   If so, how do you suggest we correct?   Lastly, how would you suggest I combine this with feature reduction?

Comment: Using `kfold_df.iloc[test_index, :] = y_pred_probs` to fill in the fold_df in the for loop: when the same "test_index" appeared multiple times, will the old results be overwritten by the new results? Thanks