# sklearn: What is the Benefit of Recursive Feature Elimination With Cross-Validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

When I look at [Recursive feature elimination with cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#recursive-feature-elimination-with-cross-validation), I wonder what the practical use of [sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV) could be.

Actually, it just gives me the optimum number of features back, but does not tell me anything *which feature these are*.

In contrast to this, [sklearn.feature_selection.RFE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) gives me back the `rfe.ranking_`

Shouldn't I use only `sklearn.feature_selection.RFE` accordingly?

Or do I overlook something?

Comment: what about `sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV().ranking_` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The core idea behind these two functions is same, i.e. to recursively eliminated features which are less importance than the other. The difference is how these two work to achieve that.

sklearn.feature_selection.RFE simply trains an estimator that assigns weights to features. It takes out the feature importances based on that estimator and recursively prunes it.

Recursive feature elimination with cross-validation on the other hand, add Cross-validation into the mix. The calculation of score for feature importances is done based on the validation data only. This can be a more resource consuming process depending the size of data and the estimator used.

As @Jan K has mentioned, you can get the feature ranking using the `ranking_` attribute

As per the documentation

**support_ : array of shape [n_features]**

> ```
> The mask of selected features.
> ```

This returns a boolean mask of selected features like

```
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

**ranking_ : array of shape [n_features]**

> The feature ranking, such that ranking_[i] corresponds to the ranking position of the i-th feature. Selected (i.e., estimated best)features are assigned rank 1.

For example ([from official documentation example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV))

```
selector.ranking_
#output : array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2, 5])
```

where selector is the RFECV() object

Refrences

- [Difference between RFE and SelectKfromModel](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23539/difference-between-rfe-and-selectfrommodel-in-scikit-learn)
- [How does RFECV makes use of CV](https://www.quora.com/scikit-learn-How-does-RFECV-make-use-of-cross-validation)
- [Another answer on RFECV and GridSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059123/scikit-learn-feature-reduction-using-rfecv-and-gridsearch-where-are-the-coeff)

Comment: Hi Mohammed, can you please explain in detail the line "The calculation of the score for feature importance is done based on the validation data only." I know cross-validation is used on validation data but when we are using REFCV(), at that time we are only passing training_data to it as a parameter of fit() function, then how does REFCV use validation data for calculation?

Comment: @Aman @Mohammed Kasif My guess is that the training data we passed is still split into several sets of train test splits itself. For example, assume the training data we passed were split into 3 groups.My guess is that the basic cycle for RFECV is (1) split the data into `n` - in this example 3 - number of "splits" or "groups". (2)Train model on "train" groups/splits. (3) Test model accuracy by getting some accuracy score using the "test" data set. (4) Prune feature based on the `feature_importance` attribute that most learning models generate. Could anyone clarify or correct my assumption?

Comment: I might have found another question that adds details on how RFECV works: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305191/understanding-cross-validated-recursive-feature-elimination#

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer provided, I found the following code from which I was able to print the feature name that corresponds to the respective rank. Don't recall where I found it.

```
names = data.columns
print("Features sorted by their rank:")
print(sorted(zip(map(lambda x: round(x, 4), rfecv.ranking_), names)))
```